# How to load resources from node_modules

Tags: javascript, html, css, node-modules

I'm trying to use this [emoji plugin](https://github.com/mervick/emojionearea) in my project. I installed it and I can see it in the node_modules files but I can't load it I get. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

Here is my try

```
 <head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-  fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/memory.css">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M"
crossorigin="anonymous">

 <!-- How to link them correctely -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/emojionearea/dist/emojionearea.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/emojionearea/dist/emojionearea.min.js"></script>
 </head>
```

Comment: What is the exact text of the 404 error you are seeing in the console? Is that html file in the same directory as the node_modules directory?

Comment: @mikkelrd yes the html is in the same directory Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 emojionearea.min.css  (Not Found) Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 emojionearea.min.js  (Not Found)

Comment: have you tried `href="./node_modules/ ... `?

Comment: @admcfajn Yes the same problem

Comment: the path should be `/node_modules/...` with the leading forward slash

Comment: @mikkelrd I set it like this also the same problem :(

Comment: Or does the html file get moved to a /dist folder by your environment/bundler? You might need to backtrack a couple dirs `href="../../node_modules/ ...` You're just using vanilla html, no webpack/yarn/grunt or anything?

Comment: I use webpack and a bundle.js I tried to open it by clicking on it it says Unable to open even though the path is correct